# Modify list with io module in python

Tags: python, list, module, io, overwrite

I'm trying to overwrite a line of text with the io module, the problem is that when I run my script and check my .txt the line that I overwritten is fine except for the end of the file.

```py
from io import open

text = open("tst.txt", "r+")
list_j = text.readlines()
list_j[0] = "Modified\n"
text.seek(0)
text.writelines(list_j)
text.close
```

**txt file before**

```
first line of text
second line of text
third line of text
fourth line of text
```

**txt file after**

```
Modified
second line of text
third line of text
fourth line of text
 of text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement code is okay. You gotta edit 9th line to write it to the file correctly.

```
from io import open

text = open("tst.txt", "r+")
list_j = text.readlines()
list_j[0] = "Modified\n"
text.seek(0)
#text.writelines(list_j)
with open('tst.txt', 'w+') as the_file:
    for x in list_j:
        the_file.write(x)
text.close
```